# How so I work out how many circles per ring / which ring a circle is on

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Lets say I have a bunch of circles I want to arrange in rings. The circles start in the centre and move to a new ring with a bigger diameter each time an inner ring runs out of room.

How would I know how many rings I would need to fit N amount of items and even what ring a certain circle would end up upon ?

Right now I can brute force it by iterating through the rings but I don't have a nice algorithmn for this.
[image]

Comment: There many things that can be called a "ring" of circles... Do you mean mutually externally tangent circles whose centers are regularly spaced on a common circle ? As well, what do you mean by "each time an inner ring runs out of room" ? Some little drawings could be very useful !

Comment: So on the diagram above we can only fit one circle on the first ring, 6 on the second and 12 on the third. I want to know given X number of items can we figure out how many of these rings would we end up with in the diagram above 19 gives us three rings. And can we figure out what ring a certain circle is on? In the diagram above the 19th circle should be in the last ring. (assuming we lay the circles starting from the middle outwards)

Comment: The densest packing of circles is [hexagonal packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) which has $1,6,12,18,24,30,\dots$ in each ring.  The way your third ring is drawn I don't know how many circles there will be in the next one, and the one after that. In the hexagonal packing, there are $6(n-1)$ circles in ring $n$ except for the  $1$ circle in ring $1$.  The last one in ring $n$ is then $1+3n(n-1)$

Comment: If you put centers of the circles in the third and fourth rings on circles, as it appears you have for the third, you would need $12+2\pi$ in the fourth ring, which gets difficult.

Comment: @RossMillikan How come its 12+2π  for the 4th ring ?

Comment: Because the radius increases by $1$.  It is actually a little less, but I don't think you can get a circle of $18$ to close around the one you show.  It does work with the hexagonal packing.

Comment: Thank you this was a huge help !